# In The Old Reader, how do I add a feed to multiple folders?

Tags: rss, rss-reader, the-old-reader

I just migrated my RSS feeds from Google Reader to [The Old Reader](http://theoldreader.com/).  But after adding a new feed in The Old Reader, how do I give it multiple tags?  Tags are visualized as folders, so another way to ask the question is, in The Old Reader, how do I add a feed to multiple folders?